# Why is payload URL optional in Facebook Send API

Tags: facebook

I am using the Facebook Send API and I wonder why the `url` property of `message.attachment.payload` is optional? I don't understand how you would send a file without specifying a URL, am I missing something or is this just an error in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

As of writing this, there seems to be a missing field in the API table : you can specify a `attachment_id` to reuse a previously uploaded attachement.